# Is there a way to conditionally `fmt` a string?

Tags: string, go, printf

Is there a way to conditionally fill in a string with a format placeholder in Go? In other words just ignore extra arguments. For example:

```
foo := fmt.CondSprintf("foo", "bar")
// "foo" instead of "foo%!(EXTRA string=bar)"
foobar := fmt.CondSprintf("foo%s", "bar")
// "foobar"
foobar := fmt.CondSprintf("foo%s", "bar", "baz")
// "foobar"
```

I can imagine something that tests for a specific format specifier, but I am trying to account for *all* format specifiers. A method like `num := fmt.CountReplacements("foo")` so that I could build a big `switch` statement could work too.

Comment: That idea breaks down when there is more than one parameter.  What will `fmt.CondSprintf("foo%s","bar","baz")` print? Instead, pass variables that are initialized conditionally.

Comment: @Burak Serdar I'm not sure I understand. You can just ignore any extras.

Comment: That means you don't want optional args, you just want to ignore extra args. More often than not, that's an indication of a bug, thus the `!(EXTRA)`

Comment: @Burak Serdar Yes, exactly. I don't think it's a bug in all cases.

Comment: If you need optional string args to fmt.Sprintf, declare a string variable and initialize it conditionally, but print it unconditionally. That's readable, does what you need, and safer.

Comment: It's the other way around. I have a string that conditionally contains a format specifier and I want to fill it in with a fixed value only if the string contains a format specifier.

Comment: If there is only one, then use strings.Replace instead.

Comment: So the TL;DR: is you want a version of `fmt.Sprintf` that magically works around bugs you're written?

Comment: I'd say this is either an XY Problem, or you're trying to write intentionally broken code. Either way, I'd say don't do that. What is the actual problem to be solved?

Comment: @Flimzy can you please explain why you consider this a bug? Is there a security, performance, or logical reason why trying to format a string unknown at compile time is a bad idea? You can't possibly conceive of a scenario where you might have dynamic format strings being resolved against a fixed set values?

Comment: @dcow: Sending too many arguments to a function doesn't seem like a bug to you?

Comment: "Is there a ... logical reason why trying to format a string unknown at compile time is a bad idea?" Whoever said anything about compile time?

Comment: @Flimzy it's a _variable argument_ function... by definition you can send different numbers of args and it's up to the function to interpret them however it wants. Does ignoring extra arguments if they aren't needed seem like a bug? Plenty of functions ignore arguments that aren't needed based on some context or state or other argument, etc. var-arg or not. Not sure what your point about compile time is. My use case is I want to accept a string at run time from the user and format it for them. I can write stuff myself I just don't want to re-implement something that unknown to me, might exist.

Comment: My point about compile time is I don't know what your point about compile time is.

Comment: So you have potentially bad input coming from users, and you want code that magically converts that into something usable?  If it were my program, I'd probably return an error in such a case, or be content with the user getting bogus output.

Comment: I don't want anything magical. I want to allow a user to pass in strings with optional format replacements, like when you convert time to a string using a time format string... it only formats what's specified. Go supports positional format specifiers. It's entirely possible for a user to pass in a format string and expect that the 2nd numbered format specifier gets replaced with some useful metric related to the program operation, and the first with some piece of contextual configuration, etc. It's not a foreign concept. The `fmt` package is super powerful, I want to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do similar to what you want with `template`:

```
var phrase bytes.Buffer
template.Must(template.New("").Parse("foo{{index . 0}}")).Execute(&phrase, []string{"bar", "baz"})
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ekGFOrkuKFv

`"foo"` yields `"foo"`,

`"foo{{index . 0}}{{index . 1}}"` yields `"foobarbaz"`

While this is hacky, the idea is useful in Java:

```
String.format(“foo%s”, “bar”, “baz”)
```

and Python

```
'foo{}'.format('bar','baz')
```

Not sure I'd call either of those implementations "buggy" and they're far cleaner and more readable than the Go code above.  Case in point, when I'm using Go templates normally, my template has several keys defined and I render a model to it that may have extra keys that should be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

**Foreword:** I released this utility in [`github.com/icza/gox`](https://github.com/icza/gox), see [`fmtx.CondSprintf()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/gox/fmtx#CondSprintf).

---

As others noted, the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package reports this because this is a bug in your code, it's a bug in how you call [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf).

So it's recommended to figure out why the format string and passed arguments don't match, and fix that code.

But to answer your question: the standard lib (specifically the `fmt` package) does not provide a way to ignore extra arguments.

But it's possible to achieve this. The key is to use *explicit argument indices*, more on that: [Replace all variables in Sprintf with same variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001449/replace-all-variables-in-sprintf-with-same-variable/37001642#37001642).

So when explicit argument indices are used, you tell in the format string which argument you want to use. And if by using argument indices you skip some arguments, that is not reported as an error.

So the idea is to extend the original format string with an additional verb which uses explicit argument index. And what should it point to? An extra, empty argument.

So to achieve what you want: add an additional, empty argument, it may be the empty string `""`. And extend the format string with a verb `%[n]s` where `n` is the number of new arguments (old arguments count plus 1).

And call `fmt.Sprintf()` with the new format string and the extended argument list.

Without further ado, here it is:

```
func CondSprintf(format string, v ...interface{}) string {
    v = append(v, "")
    format += fmt.Sprint("%[", len(v), "]s")
    return fmt.Sprintf(format, v...)
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(CondSprintf("foo", "bar"))
fmt.Println(CondSprintf("foo%s", "bar"))
fmt.Println(CondSprintf("foo%s", "bar", "baz"))
```

Output:

```
foo
foobar
foobar
```

Note that if `fmt.Sprintf()` would've been used instead of this `CondSprintf()`, the output would've been the following:

```
foo%!(EXTRA string=bar)
foobar
foobar%!(EXTRA string=baz)
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OA3LvbHd6bj).

Comment: `> So it's recommended to figure out why the format string and passed arguments don't match, and fix that code` `||`

And how do you do that with the `fmt` package? Let's say the a user has input a format string and I want to fill it in with some values. The `fmt` package would need to support introspection of the format string so I could at least write a big switch statement on the number of format specifiers or something if I were to consider any attempt to ignore extra arguments a bug.

Comment: @dcow Using user input as a format string as-is is a security risk in my opinion (a small one though), just like using user input as a query fragment without escaping.

Comment: What does the exploit look like? How can an attacker abuse this in _my_ program in order to do something _I_ have not intended? I can also assure you I've sanitized the resulting string as needed.

Comment: @dcow For example it can be used to instruct the `fmt` package to perform formatting that uses more CPU and memory than it should or what is considered "healthy". E.g. the call `fmt.Sprintf("%10000000d", 1)` will result in a string that is 10 MB!

Comment: The program is running on the same user's machine. If they want that, so be it. The only thing they'd be potentially denial of service-ing is themselves. It's an interesting point though, it just doesn't apply here.

Comment: @dcow It's your choice what you do. I've presented a solution that omits extra arguments, but I would most likely go on a different path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func CondSprintf(f string, args ...interface{}) string {
    n := strings.Count(f, "%s")
    if n < len(args) {
        args = args[:n]
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(f, args...)
}
```

You can be running this on [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_q65c-vTTLI).

As the  Burak says in a comment, this not be good idea.

Comment: Probably should do `n := strings.Count(f, "%s") - (2 * strings.Count(f, "%%"))`

Comment: Yeah that's the thing, I don't want to do some hack like test for a format string. I want to actually format a string using all possible format specifiers while allowing for the potential absence of a specifier.

Comment: `n := strings.Count(f, "%") - (2 * strings.Count(f, "%%"))` should work with all format specifiers.

Comment: @iLoveReflection This solution (with your correction) can still result in an error for certain inputs that works with `fmt.Sprintf()`, see [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/O23Qo1q0APP). My solution works with these too.